# Jest `resetModules()` is breaking `react-router-dom` Context

Tags: reactjs, mocking, react-router, jestjs

I'm testing a component which contains the [Link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md) component.
It also requires a context provided by `Service.js`.

Here is the code:

```js
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { Context } from "./Service"

const List: React.FC = () => (
    <Context.Consumer>
        {items => (
            <div>
                {items
                    .map(({ name, id }) => (
                        <Link
                            to={`/items/${id}`}
                            key={id}
                        >
                            <p>{name}</p>
                        </Link>
                    ))}
            </div>
        )}
    </Context.Consumer>
)

export default List
```

When I run the following test, I get the error:

`Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>`

Test:

```js
import React from "react"
import renderer from "react-test-renderer"
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router"

describe("<List>", () => {
    beforeEach(() => jest.resetModules())

    it("renders with zero items", () => {
        jest.doMock("./Service", () => ({
            Context: {
                Consumer: (props: any) => props.children([]),
            },
        }))
        const List = require("./List").default
        const tree = renderer
            .create(<MemoryRouter><List /></MemoryRouter>)
            .toJSON()        
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
    })

    it("renders with items", () => {
        jest.doMock("./Service", () => ({
            Context: {
                Consumer: (props: any) =>
                   props.children([{ name: "d", id: "d" }]),
            },
        }))
        const List = require("./List").default
        const tree = renderer
            // this line throws the error!
            .create(<MemoryRouter><List /></MemoryRouter>)
            .toJSON()        
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
    })
})
```

NOTE: if I remove `beforeEach(() => jest.resetModules())` the test works but it **ignores the second mock**, running with an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by forcing the re-import of the router **for each test**:

```js
    // ...
    const { MemoryRouter } = require("react-router")`
    const List = require("./List").default
    const tree = renderer
    // ...
```

Looks verbose though. Please add a better solution if you have one, thanks!